# How can I show Multiple Rows in JSON

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to show [sql result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN1VW.png)

in a JSON like this

```
{
slpcode: 700,
businesspartnerparamid:{181,
                        195,
                        197,
                        362,
                        376
                        }
}
```

in a spring boot app.

Class

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="businesspartnerparamsalesperson")
public class Vendedor {

    @Id
    @Column(name="businesspartnerparamid", nullable = false)
    private Long businessPartnerParamID;

    @Column(name="Slpcode",nullable = false)
    private Long slpCode;

    public Long getBusinessPartnerParamID() {
        return businessPartnerParamID;
    }

    public void setBusinessPartnerParamID(Long businessPartnerParamID) {
        this.businessPartnerParamID = businessPartnerParamID;
    }

    public Long getSlpCode() {
        return slpCode;
    }

    public void setSlpCode(Long slpCode) {
        slpCode = slpCode;
    }
}
```

Repo

```
Repository
public interface VendedorRepository extends JpaRepository<Vendedor, Long> {



    Optional<Vendedor> findVendedorBySlpCode (Long slpCode);



}
```

Service

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ApiService {

    @Autowired
    private final VendedorRepository vendedorRepository;

    @Autowired
    private final ClienteRepository clienteRepository;

    public Optional<Vendedor> findVendedorByCode (Long slpCode) {
        Optional<Vendedor> vendedor = vendedorRepository.findVendedorBySlpCode(slpCode);

        return vendedor;
    }

    public Optional<Cliente> findClienteByCode (String code){
        Optional<Cliente> cliente = clienteRepository.findClienteByCardCode(code);

        return cliente;
    }


}
```

Controller

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RequestMapping("/vendedor")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ApiController {

    @Autowired
    private ApiService apiService;


    @GetMapping(value="/{slpCode}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Optional<Vendedor> findVendedorBySlpCode (@PathVariable Long slpCode){
        return apiService.findVendedorByCode(slpCode);
    }
}
```

I'm getting this message on log:

> query did not return a unique result: 94; nested exception is >javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 94

After that, I wanna delete/update all of salesperson associated id's (transfer clients (id's) from one to another .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException` indicates that there is more than one result from the query. Looking at your data, indeed, you have more than one row where the `slpCode` is `700`.

You have to change the return type to List of `Vendedor`:

```
List<Vendedor> findVendedorBySlpCode (Long slpCode);
```

If no vendors are found an empty list will be returned.